# upload multiple images or file to the storge in firebase and get the uri for this and put the uri in databse

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I want anyone to teach me how to upload multiple files to Firebase Storage, as well as take the addresses of these files and put them inside the Firebase Database.

Comment: For storing the Uri in database, Cloud functions for firebase should do this trick. Write a cloud fucntion so that whenever your Storage in Firebase receives an image file it stores the uri in the Firebase Database.

Comment: Both the step of uploading an image, and of then adding the download URL to the database are covered in the [Firebase codelab for Android](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/). I highly recommend that you follow that.

Comment: Provided you know about the authentication you need to perform an upload, Uploading files to Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files

Comment: thank you , I know How to upload one file Put I need to Upload multiple  file not one

Comment: If you just know the code of uploading one file then use it in a loop where you provide new byte array for new file. What's issue in that? And also why is such question on stackoverflow. This is not a tutorial site you need to implement something first. I don't think you have tried anything just asking whole working code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no firebase storage method for uploading multiple files but it can be achieved by executing file upload method in a loop:
I hope you have all the files which you want to upload.

Try below code:

// arrayListImageFile is the ArrayList containing your files \

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayListImageFile.size(); i++) {
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(arrayListImageFile.get(i));
            uploadMethod(uri, i);
        }
```

Here is the upload method:
// arrayListImageDownloadUri is ArrayLisr \

```
private void uploadImageMethod(Uri uri, final int i, final String pushKey) {
    final StorageReference imageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(Constants.FIREBASE_FOLDER_INSURANCE +
            "/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid() + "/" + pushKey + "/" + i + ".jpg");

    arrayListImageRef.add(imageRef); //arraylist of type StorageRef \\
    imageRef.putFile(uri)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    imageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            arrayListImageDUrl.add(uri);

                            ArrayList<String> imageRefString = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (int i = 0; i < arrayListImageRef.size(); i++) {
                                imageRefString.add(arrayListImageRef.get(i).toString());
                            }

                            ArrayList<String> imageDUrlString = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (int i = 0; i < arrayListImageDUrl.size(); i++) {
                                imageDUrlString.add(arrayListImageDUrl.get(i).toString());
                            }

                            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                            map.put("imageRef", imageRefString);
                            map.put("imageDownloadUrl", imageDUrlString);
                            DatabaseReference dbRefLicenseDoc = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.FIREBASE_NODE_INSURANCE);
                            dbRefLicenseDoc.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()).child(pushKey)
                                    .updateChildren(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        if (i == arrayListImageUri.size() - 1) {
                                            dismissDialog();
                                            finish();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    });
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    if (!isFinishing()) {
                        dismissDialog();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

}
```

Comment: What is arrayListImageUri? Isn't it the uri passed inside uploadMethod(Uri uri, final int count) ?

Answer (score 0):

To Upload a image to Firebase Storage use this method

```
private void uploadImage(Uri filePath) {
    //filePath contains the Uri of your image or file
    if(filePath != null)
    {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("images/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        ref.putFile(filePath)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        //Here you store the uploaded Image URL as a string
                        imageUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(CompleteProfileActivity.this, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(CompleteProfileActivity.this, "Failed "+e.getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot
                                .getTotalByteCount());
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded "+(int)progress+"%");
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

If you want to upload multiple files put this in loop and pass a different Uri in each iteration.

now you have your image URL as a string, you can push that string to Firebase Database.

For example :-

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ImageUrl").setValue(imageUrl);
```

To show the uploaded image in a image view

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(/*read the string url from database*/).into(imageView);
```

Documentation is always the best place to start learning :)

[Upload Files To Firebase Storage Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files)

[Download Files From Firebase Storage Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files)

[Read and write data from Firebase Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events)

Comment: the command imageUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString(); does not work to me. The error message is: cannot resolve method getDownloadUrl().

Comment: @AlitonOliveira Yep, `getDownloadUrl()` is a method of the `StorageReference` object. So, in this case, replace the `taskSnapshot` with `ref`...